# SQL comparing 2 datetime's from the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, compare

I'm trying to compare the value of a DATETIME with other results from the column + a time component.
Basically, I need it to show if a room has overlapping times comparing a start time + duration to other start times for the room.
I've written this, so far, but I'm not sure what I actually need to be asking.

```
SELECT roomNo, startDateTime AS `start1`,
(SELECT startDateTime FROM roombooking WHERE (`start1` + duration - startDateTime) > 0 GROUP BY roomNo) AS `start-Time2`
FROM roombooking;
```

### The results should show like

```
---------------------------------------------
| roomNo | start1          | start2         |
---------------------------------------------
| 1      | 2016-12-8 12:00 | 2016-12-8 12:10|
| 1      | 2016-12-8 12:00 | 2016-12-8 12:15|
| 2      | 2016-12-8 6:00  | 2016-12-8 6:45 |
---------------------------------------------
```

Assuming the duration for the 12 meeting was > 15mins and the one for 2 was > 45mins

Comment: Overlapping with what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlapping bookings suggest a self-join:

```
select rb.*, rb2.*
from roombooking rb join
     roombooking rb2
     on rb.roomno = rb2.roomno and
        rb.startdatetime < rb2.startdatetime + interval rb2.duration minutes and
        rb.startdatetime + interval rb.duration minutes > rb.startdatetime;
```

Note:  This assumes that the duration is measured in minutes.